# CodeIgniter route overridden by controller/method

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I have in my `routes.php`:

```
$route['ctrller1/method1/video/(:num)'] = 'ctrller2/method2/$1';
```

I also have a controller that is named `ctrller1` that has a method:

```
function method1 ($str = NULL) {
    // do something
}
```

The problem is I have to use controller2 coz I can't or shouldn't edit controller1. What I want is seemingly simple but, apparently, CI doesn't want to work with me.

When the url:
`domain.com/ctrller1/method1/edit`
is invoked, I want the method inside `ctrller1` to be called, if `domain.com/ctrller1/method1/videos/1`
is invoked I want the method in `ctrller2` called.

It all seems correct to me but it won't work. So, I must be missing something. I've tried adding this to the routing:

```
$route['ctrller1/method1/(edit)'] = 'ctrller1/method1/($1)';
```

But it's a no go. Anyone see anything wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At any time when you work with routes, just like permissions (firewall, etc;) order is important.  Typically you want to organize your routes in this order:

1. MOST DEFINED
2. LESS DEFINED
3. GENERAL / FALLBACK

To clarify, that means your order for routes should be like this:

```
$route['ctrller1/method1/videos/view/(:num)'] = 'ctrller2/method3/$1';
$route['ctrller1/method1/videos/(:num)'] = 'ctrller2/method2/$1';
$route['ctrller1/(:num)'] = 'ctrller2/method1/$1';
```

When the URL is called, the route table goes through and finds the FIRST closest match, ELSE it traverses to the next route.

In this case what you want is something like this:

> domain.com/ctrller1/method1/videos/1
>   domain.com/ctrller1/method1/edit

Reasoning for that is, the video's route is more specific, and also is a SPECIAL CASE, as you route it to another controller behind the scenes.

Here is what your routes should look like then (not tested, but should be it):

```
$route['ctrller1/method1/videos/(:num)'] = 'ctrller2/method2/$1';
$route['ctrller1/method1/edit'] = 'ctrller1/method1';
```

As a side, note, I am curious why you format it `ctrller1/method1/videos/` and not something like `ctrller1/videos/view/12355` or `ctrller1/videos/edit/12355`, the `method1` seems confusing. But again I don't have all the details here.

Hope that works for you, if not comment, and I will revisit your question if you clarify it a little more.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have `video` on one place and `videos` on another?

Either change to

```
$route['ctrller1/method1/videos/(:num)'] = 'ctrller2/method2/$1';
```

or try url: domain.com/ctrller1/method1/*video*/1

Comment: Nah. That's a typo on the question only. I've checked my code and everything seems to be in order.